# iPhone storing website favicon even though it's been updated and cache/history is cleared

Tags: html, css, ios, safari, favicon

The icon that displays on my iPhone XS (Safari) is incorrect. If I bookmark the site or add to favourites the new/correct image is displayed but if I click the 'tab' icon, where you see all open tabs it's a very old favicon.

The image that is displayed isn't my the hosting. I've even changed hosting provider recently so everything is fresh. I can only assume the previous icon is cached from the old site on my phone - but the same domain name.

I have cleared Safari's cache and in "Advanced" the "Website Data" but no matter what I do the icon won't change. I've tried adding `?v=2` to the URL to try and force a fresh download but no matter what, it won't display the image I'm specifying in the `head`.

I load my icons like this:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.png" sizes="192x192">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" sizes="32x32">
```

Any ideas? The only thing I can think of is the device itself is storing aspects on websites but outside of Safari and the cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting, with further research I found out it's a known issue for Safari IOS/IpadOS to cache favicons in a hidden location.

> Safari has extremely aggressive favicon cache. I've seen it happen multiple times on large production websites that the favicon doesn't update for months.

[source](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=25866881)

It seems like [MacOS](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2020/09/08/refresh-favicons-in-safari-mac/) has a folder that stores that data, but unfortunately that location is not accessible via mobile (to my knowledge).

Without giving you a fix for you issue, I hope that my answer might bring light on this cache issue, as I'm experiencing the same problem on my IPhone 13 pro 15.6.1

Kindest regards

Comment: Thanks, yeah it's really strange! I could report on Apple but can't imagine it's a high priority! Not sure I can bring myself to factory reset my OS just to change the icon haha.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found the following.... use the "+" in safari to go to your START PAGE, then delete ALL instances of that page, go to edit at the bottom and turn off favorites, then turn it back on. The favicon updated.

Comment: I deleted the favourite. Then disabled favourites. Closed the browser, enabled favourites again. Then went back to the website and saved but it was still the same icon unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

I cleared the Safari cache on Settings (`Clear History and Website Data` option) but that didn't work.

However, I restarted my phone (after that) just to see and it worked!